# How do I solve the discord error. TypeError: bot.Memory.Guilds is not iterable

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

First, the bot starts, everything is fine, and then it gives an error

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordbot\events\ready.js:30
        for (const guild of bot.Memory.Guilds)
                                       ^

TypeError: bot.Memory.Guilds is not iterable
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordbot\events\ready.js:30:40)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers(node:internal/timers:512:7)

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Here are the lines of code that gives the error

```
setInterval(async() => {
        for (const guild of bot.Memory.Guilds) {
            const cacheGuild = guild.cache;
            for (const it of guild.muted) {
                if(it.time+it.date<Date.now()) {
                    const user = await cacheGuild.members.fetch(it.id);
                    if(!user) break;
                    user.roles.remove("911636933791334440");
                    if(user.voice.channel) user.voice.setMute(false);
                    guild.muted.splice(guild.muted.indexOf(it),1);
                }
            }
        }
    }, 5000);
```

I'm trying to solve the problem, if someone can help, thanks in advance

Comment: What is `bot.Memory.Guilds`?

Comment: guild is a server.
It contains information about everyone, as well as useful functions related to presence cases and so on.

Comment: I know what a guild is :) What I wanted to know is what the value of `bot.Memory.Guilds` is and where it's coming from. Sorry for not being clear enough the first time.

Comment: in theory, there should be a check to see if the user is tortured, check his roles and remove it